# Creating a search text field

Tags: ios, swift, list, search, uitextfield

I want to create a search mechanism for IOS that looks something similar to the homepage of Maps.

[image: start]

[image: finish]

Basically I want to create a text field. Then, when somebody clicks on it, I want the text field to move to the top while also showing a list of items below. I have no idea how I would even start this. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView programmatically or nib file whichever suitable for you consisting all component [uitextfield,..]. Add created UIView at bottom of you main View, making sure uitextfield is visible!

Use **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to move your view up and down on dragging movement by the User.

```
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
```

Handling transition you may use below code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                    sender.view.frame = newPosition;
                } completion:nil];
```

You need animate uiview even when user touches uitextfield, so check the position of uiview whether it is you should animate it up or not.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     if(yourView.frame.origin.y < visibleYOfYourView) {
     //animate YourView Up
     }
}
```

There are many other ways to implement, this is something came to my mind! hope it helps you.